# Can someone explain me this line? I got this from Telesko Django playlist video number 20

Tags: django

This urls.py of base project

```
urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is the settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets')

MEDIA_URL ='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

This code is to add items to the database dynamically and i am not able to understand why is he adding the urlpatterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He is adding media urls to the url patterns. So for example if you had an image or video or something stored in your django project, you can use the browser to access these files at `MEDIA_URL`. In the settings.py, you are setting `MEDIA_URL` (where you can go in the browser '/media/'), to point to the contents of your `MEDIA_ROOT` (the 'media' folder)